# two column compare ,get count(*) of two column A value same cloumn B value

Tags: mysql, select

I have a Mysql table as

```
---------------------
-- page   -  user  --
---------------------
-- page a - user 1 --
-- page a - user 2 --
-- page a - user 3 --
-- page b - user 1 --
-- page b - user 3 --
-- page c - user 3 --
-- page d - user 2 --
---------------------
```

I need to get the result as

```
---------------------------------
-- page_a  -  page_b  -  cnt   --
---------------------------------
-- page a  - page  b  -    2   --
-- page a  - page  c  -    1   --
-- page a  - page  d  -    1   --
-- page b  - page  c  -    1   --
-- page b  - page  d  -    0   --
-- page c  - page  d  -    0   --
---------------------------------
```

Since this table is really big (200K rows) I tried PHP solution by compare in pair (with 1000pages). Since it will resulted in almost 500K answers, it takes more than one day to finish (about 5 each second).

```
------------------------------------------------
MYSQL: script 
----------------------------------------------- 
select count(user) as cnt 
FROM (select user 
FROM table where page='".$a."') as a 
WHERE a.user in (select user FROM table where page='".$b."')
-----------------------------------------------
```

to get the count then insert into table by php statement.

I like to try mysql approach to see if pure sql can be faster
Any Help ?